# How can I find values in an array which match criteria, without using a for loop?

Tags: php, arrays, filtering

I have an array like this

```
$a = [
    [
        "id"     => "1",
        "values"   => [
            "1",
            "2"
        ]
    ],
    [
        "id"     => "2",
        "values"   => [
            "1",
            "3"
        ]
    ],
    [
        "id"     => "3",
        "values"   => [
            "2",
            "4"
        ]
    ],
    [
        "id"     => "4",
        "values"   => [
            "4",
            "6"
        ]
    ],
];
```

to search and return the array that 'values' has 2

```
$result = [
    [
        "id"     => "1",
        "values"   => [
            "1",
            "2"
        ]
    ],
    [
        "id"     => "3",
        "values"   => [
            "2",
            "4"
        ]
    ],
];
```

Yes, I can do with for loop, and use in_array to return the result, just thinking whether there is elegant (better) way to do it?

```
$result = [];
foreach ($a as $datum) {
    if (in_array('2', $datum['values'])) {
        $result[] = $datum;
    }
}
```

I tried array_search, but it does not support nested array

`array_search('2', array_column($a, 'values'));`

Comment: array_filter? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: oh,yes, and is there any way to ignore to use in_array to check?     array_filter($data, function($datum) {
        if (in_array('2', $datum['values'])) {
            return $datum;
        }
    });

Comment: It would be something like this: array_filter($data, function($datum) { return in_array('2', $datum['values']); });

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_filter()` and `in_array()`:

```
$value = '2';

$result = array_filter($a, function (array $element) use ($value) {
    return array_key_exists('values', $element) 
        && is_array($element['values']) 
        && in_array($value, $element['values'], true);
});

var_dump($result);
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

For an example, see:

- https://3v4l.org/4HnFV